# ¿Loop para realizar updates en varias DB al mismo tiempo?

Tags: sql, while, base-de-datos

Estoy buscando la forma de realizar el mismo cambio a diferentes bases de datos que comienzan y terminan con la misma sintaxis, solo cambia el numero de base.

Tengo el siguiente código pero no me funciona, solo actualiza la primera Base

```sql
DECLARE @numero_alumno INT
DECLARE @base_inicio varchar(10)
SET @base_inicio = 'Base_0'
DECLARE @base_fin varchar(10)
SET @base_fin = '_AM'
SET @numero_alumno = 1
DECLARE @Base_de_datos varchar(50)

WHILE @numero_alumno < 10
BEGIN
    SET @Base_de_datos = @base_inicio+cast(@numero_alumno AS Varchar(1))+@base_fin
    EXEC('USE '+ @Base_de_datos)
    UPDATE RPARAMS SET Param='Dato_que_cambiare' WHERE copar='CONFIGUR'
    SET @numero_alumno = @numero_alumno + 1
    PRINT @Base_de_datos
END

PRINT 'Realizado'
GO
```

Comment: Parece que tienes una base de datos por alumno. Si puedes, revisa este diseño para que quede en una sola base de datos. En un modelo bien diseñado, rara vez deberías necesitar ciclos para cumplir tu objetivo.

Comment: Efectivamente es por alumno, pero es para capacitaciones, si todos los alumnos usaran la misma db, los cambios realizados en 1 se reflejaria en todos.

Comment: En vez de tener tablas separadas por alumno, es mejor tener una sola tabla pero con registros diferentes por alumno. Sería solo cuestión de modificar las tablas necesarias para que tengan una columna `AlumnoId`, o algo por el estilo, que te permita identificar a cual alumno pertenece el registro. Diseñado de esta forma, es fácil modificar los datos de un alumno en particular sin afectar los demás, pero a la vez es igual de fácil ponerlos todos al día si necesitas hacerlo en ciertos casos, como es el caso en tu pregunta.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no es que sea un modelo que pueda cambiar, es un software que se alimenta de la base y la base tiene almenos 50 tablas y cada alumno realizara acciones diferentes. para modificar la db estructuralmente requiero modificar todo a nivel de empresa.

Comment: Lo siento. ¿Estás usando SQL Server, cierto?

Comment: Si SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución inmediata a tu problema es de generar el `UPDATE` de forma dinámica incluyendo el nombre de base de datos en la sentencia para identificar la tabla, y luego usando `EXEC` para ejecutar el `UPDATE`.

O sea que, en vez de:

```
EXEC('USE '+ @Base_de_datos)
UPDATE RPARAMS SET Param='Dato_que_cambiare' WHERE copar='CONFIGUR'
```

Reemplaza estas 2 sentencias con esta:

```
EXEC('UPDATE ' + @Base_de_datos + '..RPARAMS SET Param=''Dato_que_cambiare'' WHERE copar=''CONFIGUR''')
```

---

Pero repitiendo lo que te dejé en los comentarios, el que tengas que emplear SQL dinámico en un ciclo es una fuerte indicación de que el diseño de tu modelo no es correcto.  No es buen diseño que las tablas estén repetidas en diferentes bases de datos para cada alumno.

Mas bien, lo normal es que definas una base de datos, con una sola estructura de tablas compartida por todos los alumnos, y que cada alumno tenga sus propios registros identificados por una columna `AlumnoId` o algo por el estilo.

Por ejemplo, tomando el ejemplo en tu pregunta, en vez de tener varias tablas `RPARAMS` en diferentes bases de datos, solo necesitarías una, pero con una columna `AlumnoId` para poder distinguir los registros de cada alumno y poder manipularlos separadamente cuando es necesario.

Con este diseño, tu problema sería resuelto ejecutando una sola sentencia `UPDATE` sin necesidad de ciclos ni SQL dinámico:

```
UPDATE RPARAMS
   SET Param='Dato_que_cambiare'
 WHERE copar='CONFIGUR'
```

Y si necesitaras poner al día un dato para un solo alumno en paricular, sería solo cuestión de agregar un filtro adicional a la sentencia:

```
UPDATE RPARAMS
   SET Param='Dato_que_cambiare'
 WHERE copar='CONFIGUR'
   AND AlumnoId = 5
```

Comment: Funciono perfecto gracias!